# Get element by scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a simple page with a bunch of elements stacked vertically, for example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container > * {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some title</h1>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <p>Lorem ips dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cill dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est labor.</p>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <h1>Another title</h1>
  <p>Another random content</p>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
</div>
```

I need to find an element at specific scroll position, so it looks like this:

```js
function getElementByScrollPosition(yPosition) {
  // ...
  return element;
}

getElementByScrollPosition(600); // get element at 600 scrollY (or offsetTop)
```

My question is, how to do this efficiently? My current plan is to loop through every element of the page and `getBoundingClientRect()` each. Then compare position of each item. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use js `document.elementFromPoint()`

Check more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint):

> The elementFromPoint() method, available on the Document object, returns the topmost Element at the specified coordinates (relative to the viewport).

Example:

```js
console.log(document.elementFromPoint(300,150));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container > * {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some title</h1>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <p>Lorem ips dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cill dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est labor.</p>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <h1>Another title</h1>
  <p>Another random content</p>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#element').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#element').fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container>* {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

#element {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="element">This gets displayed after 100px of scrolling</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Some title</h1>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <p>Lorem ips dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis
    aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cill dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est labor.</p>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <h1>Another title</h1>
  <p>Another random content</p>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
</div>
```

In this example, you can show and hide a specific element if you scroll more or less than `100px`. If you want it more automatized, I would recommend you for example [Sal](https://mciastek.github.io/sal/).

Comment: Sorry, but as my understanding, OP want to get the html (tag, id, class) at that specific coordinates. Maybe I am wrong ?~